# Can I use Crystal Reports in Visual Studio 2022?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crystal-reports, visual-studio-2022

Has anyone tried Crystal Reports with Visual Studio 2022?

I have an ASP.NET MVC app using Bootstrap and Crystal Reports. Wondering if I can run and maintain it in Visual Studio 2022...

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/crystal-report-is-not-support-visual-studio-2022/1479512

Comment: The link in the comment above is quite old. It is from 5 months ago. The question from the OP is valid because VS2022 has now been in General Availability for a month. I am asking the same questions because there is no update on it. I contacted SAP and they said "SP30 should run fine in VS2022." But when I tried it, the designer would not open.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Crystal report patch for Visual Studio 2022 is SP32, which has been released. The download address is:
[CR for Visual Studio SP32 64b installer (VS 2022 and above)](https://origin-az.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/file/0020000000661582022),or just download runtime:[CR for Visual Studio SP32 CR Runtime 64-bit](https://origin-az.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/file/0020000000661912022).
Uninstall the old version first, and then download the new version to install.
Here are the official release notes：

1. Microsoft Visual Studio 2022 (64bit)
2. Security updates
3. Addressed customer Incidents
4. New Data source: HANA 2.0 SP06
5. Platform support: Win 10 21H2
6. Platform support: Win 11 21H2 - Check KBA 3204578 for a Windows 11 specific OLE image issue and workaround.
   Platform support: Chrome Browser version 101

Comment: Is it available for 32 bit ?

Comment: [CR for Visual Studio SP32 32b installer (VS 2019 and below)](https://origin-az.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/file/0020000000661642022)

Comment: The only problem with that installer (32-bit) is that I only have VS2022 installed, so the SP32 32b installer won't let it run. I suppose I can try to reinstall VS2019 just to get the 32-bit versions installed, but that seems like a lot of hoops to jump through.

Comment: If anyone is having problems trying to load a .rpt file (it shows as a binary file) in Visual Studio 2022, try reinstalling SAP for Visual Studio as an administrator.

Comment: Is this working for community version of visual Studio?

Answer (score 4):

This is the response from SAP.
Wait for SP32.

https://answers.sap.com/questions/13463389/crystal-report-with-visual-studio-2022-preview.html

> Hi All,
>
> Dell and I have already said it's currently not supported, check the
> Platforms link Dell posted. I have it installed and it's working
> mostly for me for old projects.
>
> Or the one for CR for VS here that's on the WIKI:
>
> SAP Crystal Reports, Developer Version for Microsoft Visual Studio –
> Supported Platforms (http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-21990)
>
> Since it's 64 bit only we are building a 64 version of the Embedded
> Report Designer and integrating it into VS 2022.
>
> From what I understand there will be a separate installer for VS 2022.
> I'll know more later when I get updates from R&D.
>
> Have fun and Merry Christmas and Happy New Year.
>
> Don

Answer (score 3):

CR for VS 2022 requires a 64 bit installer so it can integrate with the VS IDE, has CR Designer Basic built in 64 bit now.
At this time SP 34 is available.
NOTE: CR for VS does NOT SUPPORT the Nuget package, please don't use it, it comes from a third party site and they have reversioned it.
Please download it from here or the WIKI link above:
https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html
Select CR for Visual Studio SP34 64b installer (VS 2022 and above)
https://origin-az.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/file/0020000000674372023
At the end it prompts to install the 32 bit runtime also.
You can set the Project Properties to x86 or x64, don't use AnyCPU, CR runtime is your app platform and not the OS Platform.
VS 2022 does have issue creating WEB app's in one project type, sorry I don't recall what it is, but if it doesn't work then you know...
Set IIS to x86 or x64 and then build your project for the same, you'll notice the location redirects to the correct folder.
To help upgrading I wrote a Blog on how to:
https://blogs.sap.com/2020/10/30/upgrading-a-visual-studio-2008-2019-.net-project-with-the-latest-cr-.net-sdk-packages/
Pay attention to the Copy Local, must be set to False, you cannot distribute the runtime files manually, you must use the MSI packages to distribute.
Also note due to Windows Security updates you likely need to copy the CRView folder into your project as well:
Copy this folder into your app folder as a directory:
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\aspnet_client\system_web\4_0_30319\crystalreportviewers13
Don't copy the 2.0 framework version, it will cause version issues if you do.

So to answer your original question you can open your Project in VS 2022 but due to the platform change VS will update the references, I believe it defaults to x64, so change it back to x86 and it will compile in x86 mode. Problem is in your distribution, VS 2022 may add some 64 bit versions.
Note also there are a few 64 bit CR dll's that are used in either x86 or x64.
So for now I suggest not upgrading to VS 2022.

Do it when you are do upgrade to X64 across the whole project.

One final note: CR for VS is going to end x86 builds in a few years because All mother boards support 64 bit OS's so there is no reason anymore to continue supporting x86. Running IIS in 64 bit mode is also an advantage.

PS - I started at Crystal in 1997 and CR 5 was just released, it came in both 16 and 32 bit installs on FLoppy's. Time to convert everything to 64 bit, no reason to run in 32 bit mode any more...

Answer (score 1):

Steps to Follow:

1. Uninstall all the SAP Crystal Reports versions.
2. Completely close the Visual Studio (end task from task manager).
3. Download the [SAP Crystal Report Developer Edition](https://origin-az.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/file/0020000000661582022). Unzip and run the executable file.
4. Download SAP Crystal Reports Runtime Engine [64 bits](https://origin-az.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/file/0020000000661912022) or [32 bits](https://origin-az.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/file/0020000001650032022) as per the system requirement and run as administrator.
5. Ready to use the crystal report in Visual Studio 2022.

Answer (score 0):

SAP Crystal Reports does not support Visual Studio 2022 yet—not even the latest SP31. Please use other alternatives for now, or wait for SP32.

Comment: Can you provide a link to the source of this statement? Have they said they would support it in SP32?

Comment: @Michael  https://www.tektutorialshub.com/crystal-reports/how-to-download-and-install-crystal-report-runtime/

Comment: This is outdated information. SP32 has been released and supports VS 2022. [[src](https://www.sap.com/documents/2016/06/f871031e-757c-0010-82c7-eda71af511fa.html)]

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from Visual Studio 2017 to 2022. For Crystal reports, I continue to develop them in 2017. Then I copy the reports from my 2017 folder into the 2022 folder. The new/modified reports developed in 2017 work fine in 2022. I do have crystal NuGet package version 13.04.001 installed in my VS 2022 version.

Answer (score 0):

The latest version SP32 supports VS 2022
https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads

https://answers.sap.com/questions/13463389/crystal-report-with-visual-studio-2022-preview.html

https://origin.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/site/index.html

(Requires Login)
https://www.sap.com/cmp/td/sap-crystal-reports-visual-studio-trial.html

Answer (score 0):

After installing [SAP Crystal Reports for Visual Studio (SP32) installation package for Microsoft Visual Studio IDE (VS 2022 and above)](https://origin-az.softwaredownloads.sap.com/public/file/0020000000661582022)

I still couldn't add a Crystal Report to ASP.Net 4.8 project.  I had uninstalled all previous versions of CR for VS, rebooted, etc.

I had VS 2019, VS 2022 Preview and VS 2022 installed.  After removing VS 2022 Preview, updating VS 2022 and re-install of SP32 for VS IDE, everything began working.

Answer (score 0):

Uninstalling the older versions solved this problem, Run the 'setup.exe' file as administrator and don't install the MSI runtime packages. Also, install Visual c++ runtime 2013 x32 and x64

Answer (score 0):

Crystal Report ItemTemplate and Project Templates need to be copied from

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Professional\Common7\IDE
```

To

```
C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Visual Studio 2022\Templates
```

it's working for me.

[image]